# Shows the timer in console

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to show the time  during my process is making, in this case I`m showing in the format 00:00:00, so, the problem is when the process ends, how can I stop the timer.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
bool flag = true;
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
           bool flag = true;

            while (flag == true)
            {
                TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
                Console.Write(timeSpan.ToString("c"));
                Console.Write('\r');
                //HERE IS MY PROCESS

                //flag = false;

            }
```

Comment: Note that you are running "HERE IS MY PROCESS" in a while loop.  I would guess that you only want to run it once.  So, stopwatch.Start() ... PROCESS .. stopwatch.Stop() should be sufficient to get the elapsed duration of your process.  The while loop does suggest that you intended PROCESS to be a thread, and if that is the case then you should say so.

Answer (score 1):

After the while loop, add

```
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            bool flag = true;

            while (flag == true)
            {
                stopWatch.Stop();
                Console.Write(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
                Console.Write('\r');
                stopWatch.Start();
                //HERE IS MY PROCESS

                //flag = false;

            }

            stopWatch.Stop();
        }
```

You can also format the time as you please, you already have the milliseconds now =)

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to call stopwatch.Stop() from a different thread.  The stopwatch will need to be accessible from both, and you will probably need to provide locking between them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to shut it down.  Just let the GC reclaim the memory.
Trying any sort of stop or shutdown will create more work than abandoning it.

There's no processing going on in the background, all the work is done when you use `Stopwatch` methods and properties.  This is because the `Stopwatch` doesn't have its own counter, it works by reading the OS system-wide clock twice and subtracting.